# How can I make IDCT run faster on my GPU?

Tags: c, optimization, opencl, gpu

I am trying to optimize IDCT from [this](https://github.com/claf/MJPEG/tree/master/tima_seq_version/src) code for the GPU. The GPU I have on my system in **NVIDIA Tesla k20c**.

The `IDCT` function as written in the original code looks like this:

```
void IDCT(int32_t *input, uint8_t *output) {
    int32_t Y[64];
    int32_t k, l;

    for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
        for (l = 0; l < 8; l++) Y(k, l) = SCALE(input[(k << 3) + l], S_BITS);
        idct_1d(&Y(k, 0));
    }

    for (l = 0; l < 8; l++) {
        int32_t Yc[8];

        for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) Yc[k] = Y(k, l);

        idct_1d(Yc);

        for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
            int32_t r = 128 + DESCALE(Yc[k], S_BITS + 3);
            r = r > 0 ? (r < 255 ? r : 255) : 0;
            X(k, l) = r;
        }
    }
}
```

More details about the `.c` file can be found in [this](https://github.com/claf/MJPEG/blob/master/tima_seq_version/src/idct.c) link.

This function is called from `main.c` in the following way:

```
 for (index_X = 0; index_X < nb_MCU_X; index_X++) {

for (index_Y = 0; index_Y < nb_MCU_Y; index_Y++) {

for (index = 0; index < SOS_section.n; index++) {

 uint32_t component_index = component_order[index];

int nb_MCU = ((SOF_component[component_index].HV>> 4) & 0xf) * (SOF_component[component_index].HV & 0x0f);

for (chroma_ss = 0; chroma_ss < nb_MCU; chroma_ss++) {

 //unpack block function
 //iqzz function

IDCT(unZZ_MCU, YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index] + (64 * chroma_ss));

 }
//other function                    
 }
//Code continues...
```

Details of `main.c` can be found in [this](https://github.com/claf/MJPEG/blob/master/tima_seq_version/src/main.c) link.

I made a kernel out of the IDCT function in the following way:

```
__kernel void IDCT(__global int* input, __global uchar* output) 
{
 unsigned int kid= get_global_id(0);

 int Y[64]; 
 int k,l;
 int Yc[8];

 for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
 {
  for (l = 0; l < 8; l++)
  {
   Y(k,l) = SCALE(input[(k << 3) + l], S_BITS);     
  }         
 idct_1D(&Y(k,0));
 }

for (l = 0; l < 8; l++)
{
for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
{Yc[k] = Y(k, l);}

idct_1D(Yc);

for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
{

int r = 128 + DESCALE(Yc[k], S_BITS + 3);
r = r > 0 ? (r < 255 ? r : 255) : 0;
X(k, l) = r;
}

}

}
```

I am calling this kernel from `main.c` in this way:

```
    for (index_X = 0; index_X < nb_MCU_X; index_X++) {

    for (index_Y = 0; index_Y < nb_MCU_Y; index_Y++) {

    for (index = 0; index < SOS_section.n; index++) {

     uint32_t component_index = component_order[index];

     int nb_MCU = ((SOF_component[component_index].HV>> 4) & 0xf) * (SOF_component[component_index].HV & 0x0f);

     for (chroma_ss = 0; chroma_ss < nb_MCU; chroma_ss++) {

    cl_mem DCT_Input = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE|CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, 64 * sizeof(cl_int), unZZ_MCU, &ret);

    //Output buffer
    cl_mem  DCT_Output = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE| CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, (MCU_sx * MCU_sy * max_ss_h * max_ss_v) + 4, YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index] + (64 * chroma_ss), &ret);
    chk(ret, "clCreateBuffer");

    ret = clSetKernelArg(cos_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&DCT_Input);
    ret |= clSetKernelArg(cos_kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&DCT_Output);

//Timing-Start..

  start_time = wtime();

  size_t globalForInverseDCT= 1024;

  size_t localForInverseDCT= 256;

 ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, cos_kernel, 1, NULL, &globalForInverseDCT, &localForInverseDCT, 0, NULL, NULL);

//Timing-End..

 run_time = wtime() - start_time;

 ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, DCT_Output, CL_TRUE, 0, (MCU_sx * MCU_sy * max_ss_h * max_ss_v) + 4, YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index] + (64 * chroma_ss), 0, NULL, NULL);

 }

 //other function

 }

 //code continues...
```

I am using this function for timing `IDCT`:

```
double wtime()
{

   /* Use a generic timer */
   static int sec = -1;
   struct timeval tv;
   gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
   if (sec < 0) sec = tv.tv_sec;
   return (tv.tv_sec - sec) + 1.0e-6*tv.tv_usec;

}
```

The execution time for IDCT on the **CPU** with my timing method is **5 microseconds**. The execution time on the **GPU** is **20 microseconds**. (I used OpenCL's built-in profiling command as well and it gave me an execution time of 31 microseconds.)

**How can I modify my code so that it runs faster on the GPU?**

**MY WORK:**

I tried to break my kernel down into smaller kernels in [this](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/c/gcc-5.3.0/5Ss) way but I am getting static as my screen output.

I profiled the code again and I got the following output:

[image]

The execution time for my IDCT kernel according to Nvidia's Visual Profiler is **17.6 microseconds** (approx.).

**EDIT:**

I profiled my code again with the command line profiler and the execution time for idct is now **4.9 microseconds**.

**PLEASE SUGGEST HOW I CAN FURTHER OPTIMIZE MY KERNEL.**

Comment: 1. If you can get hold of any more detailed profiling information for your implementation which tells you whether you're hitting e.g. register spills, memory bottlenecks, etc., that's going to help tremendously.
2. Just skimming over your kernel code, you're probably using far too many registers (private variables) to achieve any significant parallelism.
3. We've had success with splitting 8x8 DCTs (the reverse of what you're doing) into 8 work-items, with each work-item performing a single 1D DCT, storing the result to a `local` array, awaiting a barrier, and then 1D the other direction.

Comment: Is 20 microseconds the time it takes to run the kernel? Or the whole execution including data transfer time?

Comment: I did long time ago an implementation of DCT/IDCT 1D for OpenCL, my results showed that it is faster (including transfer time) however not by much, but you have to be careful parallelizing it it is so easy to break it. Since you need many registers and proper coalescence. A 2D implementation of cooperative workgroups would be even better but harder to code. try not to just copy paste the C code, but reshape it to use less registers and all the workgroup.

Comment: @pmdj How can I get more detailed profiling information? I am only familiar with `clgeteventprofilinginfo` and the timer command I included in my question.

Comment: @parallelhighway As shown in my code snippet, I am calling start_time before `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` and `run_time = wtime() - start_time` immediately after it. Should this not give me just the execution time?

Comment: @a_sid no it will not give you the execution time actually. It will give you the time it takes to enqueue the kernel. After the enqueue call, your thread returns to the CPU side while your kernel is being executed. You would get a better timing result if you profile, or use an event and measure the time that way. Btw, wht not use nvidia profiler?

Comment: @parallelhighway I used `clgeteventprofilinginfo` and I got approx. 30 microseconds with it. I did not consider using nvidia profiler because I thought the opencl commands and the profiling technique I showed here would be sufficient. Isn't OpenCL's built-in profiling mechanism as accurate as the nvidia profiler?

Comment: @parallelhighway I got the idea for profiling from [this code](https://github.com/HandsOnOpenCL/Exercises-Solutions/blob/master/Solutions/Exercise04/C/vadd_chain.c).

Comment: @parallelhighway I profiled my code again and exported the results to to the Visual Profiler to see whether I would get more detailed feedback. I have posted a snapshot of the profiler's output in my question.

Comment: In your kernel, each thread runs exactly the same thing. You should change your code so that it runs the same calculations for consecutive data elements. By the way, are you getting the same results from OpenCL version as CPU version?

Comment: @parallelhighway What do you mean by _same results_? A video is being played as the output for both the CPU and GPU programs. However, the execution time per frame for the CPU code is about **17 ms** whereas for the GPU it is about **170 ms**.