# How can I optimize my OpenCL kernel for the GPU?

Tags: c, opencl, signal-processing

This question follows from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45927692/how-can-i-make-idct-run-faster-on-my-gpu?noredirect=1#comment78844616_45927692). **Since then, I have been working on my IDCT kernel to make it more efficient.**

This version of the kernel produces the correct output but is slow:

```
void idct_1D(__local int *Y);

 __kernel void IDCT(__global int* input, __global uchar* output) 
{
 unsigned int kid= get_global_id(0);

 __local int Y[64]; 
 int k,l;
 __local int Yc[8];

 for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
 {
  for (l = 0; l < 8; l++)
  {
   Y(k,l) = SCALE(input[(k << 3) + l], S_BITS);     
  }         
 idct_1D(&Y(k,0));
 }

for (l = 0; l < 8; l++)
{
for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
{Yc[k] = Y(k, l);}

idct_1D(Yc);

for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
{

int r = 128 + DESCALE(Yc[k], S_BITS + 3);
r = r > 0 ? (r < 255 ? r : 255) : 0;
X(k, l) = r;
}

}

}
```

I tried to make this kernel more parallel by modifying its structure in this way:

```
__kernel void IDCT(__global int* input, __global uchar* output) 
{
unsigned int kid= get_global_id(0);

    __local int Y[64]; 
    int k= get_global_id(0);
    int l;
    int lid= get_global_id(1);
    __local int Yc[8];

   if (k < 8)
    {
        for (l = 0; l < 8; l++) 

     {
     Y(k, l) = SCALE(input[(k << 3) + l], S_BITS);
     }
        idct_1D(&Y(k, 0));
    }

    if (lid < 8)
    {

        for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
    {
            Yc[k] = Y(k, lid);
    }

        idct_1D(Yc);

        for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
        {
            int r = 128 + DESCALE(Yc[k], S_BITS + 3);
            r = r > 0 ? (r < 255 ? r : 255) : 0;
            X(k, lid) = r;
        }

    }
}
```

The kernel above is giving me the correct output but I am seeing no changes in the processing speed of my code.

My `main.c` where I am calling the code from looks like this:

```
  for (index_X = 0; index_X < nb_MCU_X; index_X++) {

    for (index_Y = 0; index_Y < nb_MCU_Y; index_Y++) {

    for (index = 0; index < SOS_section.n; index++) {

     uint32_t component_index = component_order[index];

     int nb_MCU = ((SOF_component[component_index].HV>> 4) & 0xf) * (SOF_component[component_index].HV & 0x0f);

     for (chroma_ss = 0; chroma_ss < nb_MCU; chroma_ss++) {

    cl_mem DCT_Input = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE|CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, 64 * sizeof(cl_int), unZZ_MCU, &ret);

    //Output buffer
    cl_mem  DCT_Output = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE| CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, (MCU_sx * MCU_sy * max_ss_h * max_ss_v) + 4, YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index] + (64 * chroma_ss), &ret);
    chk(ret, "clCreateBuffer");

    ret = clSetKernelArg(cos_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&DCT_Input);
    ret |= clSetKernelArg(cos_kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&DCT_Output);


const size_t globalForInverseDCT[2]= {8, 8};



 ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, cos_kernel, 2, NULL, &globalForInverseDCT, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

//Timing-End..

 ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, DCT_Output, CL_TRUE, 0, (MCU_sx * MCU_sy * max_ss_h * max_ss_v) + 4, YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index] + (64 * chroma_ss), 0, NULL, NULL);

 }

 //other function

 }

 //code continues...
```

**How can I further optimize this kernel?**

EDIT:

Ideally, I wish to break `IDCT` into even smaller kernels. Thanks to the help I received in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901912/how-can-i-split-this-function-into-smaller-functions-without-sacrificing-its-fun/45903658#45903658), the regular function was broken down into smaller sub-functions like this:

```
void IDCTforX(int32_t *input, uint8_t *output) {

    int32_t Y[64];
    int32_t k, l;
    int32_t Yc[8];

    for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
        for (l = 0; l < 8; l++)
        {
            Y(k, l) = SCALE(input[(k << 3) + l], S_BITS);
        }
    }
}

void IDCTfor1dim(int32_t *input, uint8_t *output)
{
int32_t Y[64];
    int32_t k, l;
    int32_t Yc[8];

    for (k= 0; k < 8; k++)
    {
        idct_1d(&Y(k, 0));
    }
}
```

In the Y-direction:

```
void IDCTforY(int32_t *input, uint8_t *output) 
{
  int32_t Y[64];
  int32_t k, l;
  int32_t Yc[8][8];

  for (l = 0; l < 8; l++) 
  {
      for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
          Yc[l][k] = Y(k, l);
      idct_1d(Yc[l]);
   }

void IDCT_DescaleY(int32_t *input, uint8_t *output) 
{
  int32_t Y[64];
  int32_t k, l;
  int32_t Yc[8][8];

for (l = 0; l < 8; l++) 
   {
       for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) 
       {   
           int32_t r = 128 + DESCALE(Yc[l][k], S_BITS + 3);
           r = r > 0 ? (r < 255 ? r : 255) : 0;
           X(k, l) = r;
       }
   }
}
```

In `main.c`, I get the correct output when I call the functions (in place of the original function) in this sequence:

```
IDCTforX(unZZ_MCU, YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index] + (64 * chroma_ss));
IDCTfor1dim(unZZ_MCU, YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index] + (64 * chroma_ss));
IDCTforY(unZZ_MCU, YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index] + (64 * chroma_ss));
IDCT_DescaleY(unZZ_MCU, YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index] + (64 * chroma_ss));
```

I translated these functions into kernels but I am only getting a gray screen. My new kernels look like this:

```
/*---------------IDCTForX----------------------------*/

__kernel void IDCTforX(__global int *input, __global uchar *output) {

    int Y[64];
    unsigned int k= get_global_id(0);
    unsigned int l= get_global_id(1);

        if ((k < 8) && (l < 8))
            {
                Y(k, l) = SCALE(input[(k << 3) + l], S_BITS);

            }

}

/*---------------IDCTfor1Dim-------------------------*/

__kernel void IDCTfor1dim(__global int *input, __global uchar *output){

int Y[64];
unsigned int k= get_global_id(0);

    for (k= 0; k < 8; k++)
    {
        idct_1D(&Y(k, 0));
    }

}

/*---------------IDCTYSplit----------------------------*/

__kernel void IDCTYSplit(__global int *input, __global uchar *output) {

int Y[64];
      int k= get_global_id(0);
      int l= get_global_id(1);
      int Yc[8][8];

      if ((k < 8) && (l < 8))
      {
              Yc[l][k] = Y(k, l);

      }
}

/*---------------IDCTY_Inverse----------------------------*/

__kernel void IDCTY_Inverse(__global int *input, __global uchar *output) {

int Y[64];
      int l= get_global_id(0);
      int Yc[8][8];

 if (l < 8)
          {
          idct_1D(Yc[l]);
       }
}

/*---------------IDCTY_Descale----------------------------*/

__kernel void IDCTY_Descale(__global int *input, __global uchar *output) {

int Y[64];

    int l= get_global_id(0);

    int k= get_global_id(1);

      int Yc[8][8];

       if ((l < 8) && (k < 8))
           {
               int r = 128 + DESCALE(Yc[l][k], S_BITS + 3);
               r = r > 0 ? (r < 255 ? r : 255) : 0;
               X(k, l) = r;
           }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only on the order of 64 ops and 64 item buffers is way too small.  The overhead of just starting to pass data to/from the GPU is taking all of the time.  You want something not only parallelizable but more on the order of many millions to billions of ops per GPU kernel.

Comment: _You want something not only parallelizable but more on the order of many millions to billions of ops per GPU kernel._ How can I accomplish that? I am translating the code for MJPEG decoding and as far as I can comprehend, I cannot use that many operations.

Comment: Can I load the mjpeg file (it's data type is `FILE`) into the GPU's memory? That might cut down the communication overhead.